# angular 2 pouchdb and cloudant (couchdb) - how to

Tags: angular, couchdb, pouchdb, cloudant, angular-cli

Been trying to find examples of pouchdb/cloudant for angular2 latest stable release. Though there are plenty of posting about ionic2, there are none for vanilla angular2.

How to set up the final release of angular 2 with pouchdb, cloudant/couchdb?

Answer (score 2):

I began by reading a post by [Josh Morony](http://www.joshmorony.com/offline-syncing-in-ionic-2-with-pouchdb-couchdb/) which really helped! (thank you Josh great post!). My setup was for cloudant though it should be the same for couchdb.

Let me summarise what i did for my vanilla angular 2 set up, feel free to refer to Josh's post too for a detailed description of the points below. I'm assuming you already have a cloudant account and a database created (if not, you might want to start there).

1. `npm install pouchdb --save`
2. `npm install -g typings`
3. `typings install --global --save dt~pouchdb dt~pouchdb-adapter-websql dt~pouchdb-browser dt~pouchdb-core dt~pouchdb-http dt~pouchdb-mapreduce dt~pouchdb-node dt~pouchdb-replication`

NOTE: under cloudant make sure you enable CORS for your database API.

After installing all of the above, we'll need to change a few files (see below):

1. **angular-cli.json** - modify your "packages" array to reflect the following:

   ```
   "packages": [
   {
     "PouchDB": {
       "main": "pouchdb.js",
       "defaultExtension": "js"
     }
   }]
   ```
2. Create a new "service" for example "dataService" (I used `angular-cli`), you can copy paste. They key here is to "`require(pouchdb)`" and thus making it accessible to your other components via importing.

   ```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   var PouchDB = require('pouchdb');

   @Injectable()
   export class DataService {

     db: any;
     username: any;
     password: any;
     remote: any;
     data: any;

     constructor() {
       this.db = new PouchDB('YOUR_DATABASE');
       this.username = 'DATABASE_KEY';
       this.password = 'YOUR_PASSWORD';

       this.remote = 'https://YOU_ACCOUNT_NAME.cloudant.com/YOUR_DATABASE';

       let options = {
         live: true,
         retry: true,
         continuous: true,
         auth: {
           username: this.username,
           password: this.password
         }
       };

       this.db.sync(this.remote, options);

     }

     // other CRUD functions below...
   }
   ```
3. **`app.module.ts`** - import your new "`DataService`" and add it to "`providers`".
4. Now you're ready to start playing. Under your home page component for example, import the "DataService" and start calling your CRUD functions e.g. getDocuments, AddDocument etc..

NOTE: if you're going to be testing your API via postman (for example), make sure you enter your cloudant/couchdb login/password under "Authorisation". Otherwise, you'll experience permission reading errors.

Demo app: https://github.com/rrubio/Angular2PouchDdCloudant

Comment: Don't you think that store database credentials in ts files aren't secure?

Comment: That's right! if you're looking to have an external app, you'll need something like expressjs in the middle.